# Inheritance with Swift Realm, confusion

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, realm, one-to-many

I have an issue about Inheritance with my Objects in Realm.

Could you please have a look a it.   I have :

- an Object `Activity`
- an Object `Sport`  which I want to be a subclass of `Activity`
- an Object `Seminar` which I want to be a subclass of `Activity`

To make this happen I write, according to the documentation,  the following code :

```
// Base Model
class Activity: Object {
      dynamic var id = ""
      dynamic var date = NSDate()   

     override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
     }
}

// Models composed with Activity
class Nutrition: Object {
    dynamic var activity: Activity? = nil
    dynamic var quantity = 0
}

  class Sport: Object {
    dynamic var activity: Activity? = nil
    dynamic var quantity = 0
    dynamic var duration = 0
}
```

Now I have an Model `Category` which I want it to hold the activities, doesn’t matter if it’s an `Nutrition` or `Sport`.

Here is my code :

```
class Categorie: Object {

    let activities = List<Activitie>()
    dynamic var categoryType: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "categoryType"
    }

}
```

Now I try to add a `Nutrition` object to my `List<Activitie>` by doing this :

```
let nutrition =  Nutrition(value: [ "activity": [ "date": NSDate(), "id": "0" ], "quantity": 12 ])

try! realm.write {
     realm.add(nutrition, update: true)
}
```

It doesn’t work because `List<Activitie>` expect an `Activity` Object and not a `Nutrition` Object. Where am I wrong ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the article about [type erased wrappers in swift](https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/) and the [#5 option](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) I have ended up with something more flexible, here is my solution.

*( please note that the solution #5 need to be updated for Swift 3, my solution is updated for Swift 3 )*

My main Object `Activity`

```
class Activity: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and my inheritance : `Nutrition` and `Sport`

class Nutrition: Activity { }

class Sport: Activity { }

The solution according to the solution [#5 option](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) : Using a type-erased wrapper for polymorphic relationships.

If you want to store an instance of any subclass of Activity, define a type-erased wrapper that stores the type's name and the primary key.

```
class AnyActivity: Object {
    dynamic var typeName: String = ""
    dynamic var primaryKey: String = ""

    // A list of all subclasses that this wrapper can store
    static let supportedClasses: [Activity.Type] = [
        Nutrition.self,
        Sport.self
    ]

    // Construct the type-erased activity from any supported subclass
    convenience init(_ activity: Activity) {
        self.init()
        typeName = String(describing: type(of: activity))
        guard let primaryKeyName = type(of: activity).primaryKey() else {
            fatalError("`\(typeName)` does not define a primary key")
        }
        guard let primaryKeyValue = activity.value(forKey: primaryKeyName) as? String else {
            fatalError("`\(typeName)`'s primary key `\(primaryKeyName)` is not a `String`")
        }
        primaryKey = primaryKeyValue
    }

    // Dictionary to lookup subclass type from its name
    static let methodLookup: [String : Activitie.Type] = {
        var dict: [String : Activity.Type] = [:]
        for method in supportedClasses {
            dict[String(describing: method)] = method
        }
        return dict
    }()

    // Use to access the *actual* Activitie value, using `as` to upcast
    var value: Activitie {
        guard let type = AnyActivity.methodLookup[typeName] else {
            fatalError("Unknown activity `\(typeName)`")
        }
        guard let value = try! Realm().object(ofType: type, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else {
            fatalError("`\(typeName)` with primary key `\(primaryKey)` does not exist")
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Now, we can create a type that stores an AnyActivity!

```
class Category: Object {

    var categoryType: String = ""
    let activities = List<AnyActivity>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "categoryType"
    }
}
```

and to store the data :

```
let nutrition = Nutrition(value : [ "id" : "a_primary_value"] )

let category = Category(value: ["categoryType" : "0"])

category.activities.append(AnyActivity(tree))
```

To read the data we want to check the activity method, use the `value` property on `AnyActivity`

```
for activity in activities {
    if let nutrition = activity.value as? Nutrition {
       // cool it's a nutrition
    } else if let sport = activity.value as? Sport {
       // cool it's a Sport   
    } else {
        fatalError("Unknown payment method")
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to remove `fatalError("Unknown payment method")` from the example.  But seriously nice work.  I had to use this method a few years ago.  It would be nice to have better polymorphism and model inheritance using Realm though.

Answer (score 7):

You encountered one of the big problems of Realm : there is no complete polymorphism.

[This github post](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) gives a big highlight on what is possible or not, and a few possible solutions that you can use.

Quick quote from jpsim from the link above:

> Inheritance in Realm at the moment gets you:
>
> - Class methods, instance methods and properties on parent classes are
>   inherited in their child classes.
> - Methods and functions that take
>   parent classes as arguments can operate on subclasses.
>
> It does not get you:
>
> - Casting between polymorphic classes (subclass->subclass,
>   subclass->parent, parent->subclass, etc.).
> - Querying on multiple classes simultaneously.
> - Multi-class container (RLMArray/List and RLMResults/Results).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will have a look as soon as I have time, ( next week Monday! ) Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Owen is correct, in regarding OO principles, and I noticed that also, that you are not truly doing inheritance.

When an object uses another as an attribute or property, it is Association, not inheritance.  I too am reviewing whether Realm supports Table/Object level inheritance like Java does with Hibernate ... but not expecting it.

This framework while still young but powerful, is good enough for me to avoid using SQLite ... very fast, easy to use and much easier with data model  migrations !

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will have a look as soon as I have time, ( next week Monday! ) Cheers !

Comment: Hey, i understand, but looking at the Realm documentation inheritance cannot be done that way. Please look at : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance

Comment: To be sure ... inheritance has its own risks and rewards.  Many times however, it may be done better in code than in a framework.  It is not always that USUAL that data inheritance is something to even consider, since down the line, it can cause issues.  Always need to tread carefully there.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Nutrition` and `Sport` don't inherit `Activity`, they inherit `Object` and composite an `Activity` instance. To inherit `Activity`, you should do

```
class Nutrition: Activity {
    dynamic var quantity = 0
}
```

I think maybe you worried if you did above, your code did not inherit `Object` any more. But it is not true. `Nutrition` is still inherited from `Object` as `Object` is inherited by `Activity`.

Their relations are Nutrition: Activity: Object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will have a look as soon as I have time, ( next week Monday! ) Cheers !

Comment: Hey, i understand, but looking at the Realm documentation inheritance cannot be done that way. Please look at : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance

Comment: As previously pointed out, Realm does not support this kind of polymorphism. If you try to use it, you'll get a runtime RLMException as soon as you try to persist a subclass. This [code sample post on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) goes into great detail on what workarounds / best practices exist for using abstract classes / polymorphism. (And see below answer as well).

Answer (score 0):

As **Yoam Farges** pointed it out, Realm **doesn't support** :

> Casting between polymorphic classes (subclass->subclass,
>   subclass->parent, parent->subclass, etc.).

*Which is what I was trying to do.*

You guys are right when saying that my Inheritance is not an Inheritance, but as you can see in the [Realm documentation](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance.) it's how you achieve it.

Thanks to the informations I got in [this github post](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756)  I could achieved what I wanted and could keep a easy readability.

**Use an option type** for polymorphic relationships :

```
class PolyActivity: Object {
    dynamic var nutrition: Nutrition? = nil
    dynamic var sport: Sport? = nil
    dynamic var id = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Create my main Object `Activity`

```
class Activity: Object {
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
}
```

and have my `Nutrition` and `Sport` object inherited properly to `Activity`

```
class Nutrition: Activity {
    dynamic var quantity = 0
} 

class Sport: Activity {
    dynamic var quantity = 0
    dynamic var duration = 0
}
```

My `Category` object can now hold a List

```
class Categorie: Object {
    let activities = List<PolyActivity>()
    var categoryType: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "categoryType"
    }
}
```

And this is how I create my `Nutrition` object :

```
let polyActivity = PolyActivity(value : [ "id": primaryKey ] )
poly.nutrition = Nutrition(value: [ "date": NSDate(), "quantity": 0, "duration": 0 ])

let category = Category(value: ["categoryType" : "0"])
category.activities.append(polyActivity)
```

And to retrieve just use Optional Binding :

```
if let nutrition = category.activities[0].nutrition { }
```

If you guys have a **better**, **clearer**, **easier** solution please go head !

Comment: I am glad that you find a way. But for me, I think the fifth workaround on github is more general. There was even a video lecture of it on Realm website.

Comment: Oh, could you please point me out to it ? That would be great!

Comment: https://realm.io/news/altconf-hector-matos-type-erasure-magic/ https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/ It is also on the github link in your above post. It is the 5th workaround, which is the latest post.